# $f$ factors through $q$, where $q$ is the quotient map, and $f$ is a homomorphism.

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism, quotient-spaces, quotient-group

> Let $K$ be a normal subgroup of $G$ and $q:G \to G/K$ be the quotient map.  Let $f:G \to H$ be a homomorphism with $K \subseteq \ker(f)$.  Prove that $f$ factors through $q$, meaning that there exists a homomorphism $\varphi:G/K \to H$ such that $f = \varphi \circ q$.

I am not sure how to begin this problem. My idea was to write $G/K$ as $\bar{G}$, and then to define the map $q$ as $q(a)=\bar{a}$, for some $a\in G$, which means that $q$ is a homomorphism, and then to show that $\varphi:G/K \to H$ is a homomorphism. But I have no strategic map.

Answer (score 2):

**Hints:**

1. What must be the value of $\varphi(\bar a)$ for $a\in G$ if $\varphi\circ q=f$?
2. Show that it gives a *well defined* map $G/K\to H$.
3. Verify that it's a homomorphism.

Comment: For 1, I let $\varphi (\bar{a}) = a$. Thus, $\varphi (\bar{a}) = a$ and $\varphi (\bar{b}) = b$ for some $\bar{a},\bar{b}\in G/K$.
Then, for 2 we have that $ab=\varphi (\bar{ab})$ and since $\varphi (\bar{a}) \varphi (\bar{b}) = ab$, $\varphi $ is a map that is a homomorphism and is well-defined.

Comment: What you write would be a (left) inverse of the quotient map $q$ which just doesn't exist (unless $K$ is trivial).

Comment: I have changed my definition of $\varphi$. Let $\varphi$ be defined by $\varphi(gk)=f(g)$. Let $g_1k=g_2k$, then $g_1(g_2)^{-1}=1$, which means $g_1(g_2)^{-1}\in ker(f)$, and since $K\subseteq ker(f)$, we have $g_1(g_2)^{-1}\in K$. Thus, $f(g_1(g_2)^{-1})=e_H$, where $e_H$ is the identity element in $H$. Then $f(g_1)f((g_2)^{-1})=e_H$, which means that $f(g_1)=f(g_2)$. Thus, by the definition of $\varphi$, we have that $\varphi(g_1k)=\varphi(g_2k)$, which means that $\varphi$ is well-defined. 
I am working on showing that it is a homomorphism now.

Comment: It's much better now.

Comment: So, (1) we must have $\varphi(\bar a) =\varphi(q(a)) =f(a)$. $\ \ $ (2) If $\bar a=\bar b$ in $G/K$, then $a^{-1}b\in K\ \subseteq \ker f$, so $f(a^{-1}b)=1$, thus $f(a) =f(b)$. $\ \ $ (3) is straightforward.